# Is there any way to read IPTC information of an image in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to read/edit IPTC metadata of an image in `Xamarin.Forms`. Apparently, there is now way to do it out of the box from a PCL. I will use some kind of abstraction and I know there is a way to read those info in `Xamarin.iOS` using the `CoreGraphics` namespace.

However, I can't find any info about `Xamarin.Android` and how to extract or edit IPTC metadata. Does someone have any experience on that?

Any help is well appreciated!

Comment: How about this one https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet not sure if it supports Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Yeah, I came accross this one and was not sure as well. I'll give it a try and give feedback, thanks.

Comment: @JesseJiang: Unfortunatly this is not compatible with Xamarin.Forms. Moreover, it's only extracting metadata (read only). I omit to put in the title, but I need to edit the metadata as well. Thanks anyway.